# Whats a great way to perfom integration testing?

Tags: c#, .net, integration-testing

We have written our own integration test harness where we can write a number of "operations" or tests, such as "GenerateOrders".  We have a number of parameters we can use to configure the tests (such as the number of orders).  We then write a second operation to confirm the test has passed/Failed (i.e. there are(nt) orders).

The tool is used for

- Integration Testing
- Data generation
- End-to-end testing (By mixing and matching a number of tests)

It seems to work well, however requires development experience to maintain and write new tests.  Our test team would like to get involved, who have little C# development experience.

We are just about to start a new Greenfield project and I am doing some research into the optimum way to write and maintain integration tests.

The questions are as follows:

- How do you perform integration testing?
- What tool do you use for it (FitNess?, Custom?, NUnit)?

I am looking forward to peoples suggestions/comments.

Thanks in advance,

David

Comment: Are you planning on using Continuous Integration Testing?

Comment: It's not my intention to beg the question, but I believe that at least some development/c# experience can be very beneficial for testers.  This may be the time for them to pick up a little skill in the dev't department.

Comment: @McWaffletix - The custom tool we wrote is running when code is checked in, by CC.NET, so it will be run continuously :).

@Greg D - I totally agree :)  However our testers don't!  The problem is persuading them C# is fun.  It is a complete mind shift, we continually get "we are not developers"...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Integration testing may be done at a user interface level (via automated functional tests - *AFT*) or service/api interface level.

There are several tools in both cases:

I have worked on projects that successfully used [Sahi](http://sahi.co.in/) or [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) for AFT of web apps, [white](http://www.codeplex.com/white) for AFT for .NET WPF or winforms apps, [swtBot](http://www.eclipse.org/swtbot/) for AFT of Eclipse Rich client apps and [frankenstein](http://frankenstein.openqa.org/) for AFT of Java swing apps.

Fitnesse is useful for service/api level tests or for tests that run just below the UI. When done right, it has the advantage of having business-readable tests i.e. non-developers can read and understand the tests. Tools like NUnit are less useful for this purpose. [SOAPUI](http://www.soapui.org) is particularly suited for testing SOAP web services.

Factors to consider:

- **Duration**: Can you tolerate 8 hour test runs?
- **Brittleness**: AFTs can be quite brittle against an evolving application (e.g. ids and positions of widgets may change). Adequate skill and effort is needed to not hard code the changing parts.
- **Fidelity**: How close to real world do you want it to be? e.g. You may have to mock out interactions with a payment gateway unless the provider provides you a test environment that you can pummel with your tests.

Some nuances are captured [here](http://fragmental.tw/2008/09/29/where-do-acceptance-tests-go-to-die/).

Full disclosure: The author is associated with the organization behind most (not all) of the above free and open source tools.

Comment: This is what we went for in the end.  We have created a webapplication that acts like the WCFTestClient.exe although allows complex types so we can use selenium to perform Integration testing at the UI level :)

Answer (score 2):

You could try the [Concordion](http://www.concordion.org) framework for writing user acceptance tests in HTML files.  It takes a BDD-style approach.  There is a [.Net port](http://code.google.com/p/concordion-net/) as well

Answer (score 1):

It's not out of Beta yet, but [StoryTeller](http://storyteller.tigris.org/) looks promising: