# C# test dependancies

Tags: c#, integration-testing

I am very aware and agree with the opinion that tests should not be dependant on one another.

However in this instance I feel it would be beneficial.

The situation is the system under test has a step by step process that needs to be followed (there is no way to jump to a step without going through the previous ones).
In the ideal world we would get the devs to add an API to allow us to do thus, but given the constraints this will not be done.

Currently the tests being done are all end to end making failing tests difficult to analyse at times.

My question is then: **Is there a clean way I can break down these end to end tests into smaller tests, and impose some dependencies on them?**

Im aware that TestNG can do this using the @DependOn notation, is there a similar concept for C#?

Comment: Wait... are we talking about _unit_ tests? Why aren't the authors writing their own unit tests?

Comment: I think he is talking about integration tests more than unit tests, since he mentions that the tests are end-to-end scenarios.

Comment: @Brian but he pictured that as if writing functional/integration tests was bad - and he also mentioned he's trying to decouple the bits of the system under test, which makes me think he's trying to write unit tests. He wasn't clear on this point.

Comment: @dcastro - Oh, I don't disagree with you at all.  I think the OP needs to be a bit more clear of his intentions/pain points, in fact.

Comment: @dcastro this is more from an integration perspective. Not so much decoupling the system under test, but breaking down the number of interactions covered by one test

Comment: I'm no QA expert, but isn't it expected that one fault in the system may cause several tests to fail? You may write 10 functional tests testing the same feature, but with different inputs, for example. A change in the algorithm might cause 1, 2, or all 10 to break.

Comment: @dcastro yes, the biggest issue being faced, is that if the one test fails, then its not always the easiest to tell where in the test it failed for some of the staff involved

Comment: As much as I can, I **always** try to design my test automation using the [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_(object-oriented_design)) design pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with almost all the comments to date, the solution I ended up going with be it not the cleanest or most 'SOLID', was to use nUnit as the framework, using the [category](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=category&r=2.2) attribute to order the tests.

Answer (score 1):

From the way you describe your tests, either:

1. The way the developers have developed the code is flawed, in that to test step 3 say, steps 1 and 2 must be invoked first, rather than being able to isolate step 3. If the problem is with the way the developers designed the system, suggest they fix it.
2. You are performing integration tests and want to test the results of invoking several steps. In that case, you do not want to use a unit test tool, you need an integration test tool. [See this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/862282/7122) for advice on such tools and their pitfalls.

Comment: it is case 1, the problem being that as mentioned due to various constraints it has been decided that it wont be fixed

Comment: @Calum In that case the decision has been made to not make the code suitable for testing with unit tests, so it cannot be unit tested. TestNG support of `@DependOn` makes a mockery of the idea of unit testing. Unit tests cannot depend on other unit tests, for then they are not units.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of concepts might be useful here:

- [Scenario-Driven Tests](http://ayende.com/blog/4218/scenario-driven-tests)
- [One Assert Per Test](http://maxheapsize.com/2011/06/14/one-assert-per-test-really)

The basic idea here is to separate the scenario you are executing from the assertion you are making (i.e. what you are testing). This is really just BDD, so it may make sense to use a [BDD Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307895/what-is-the-most-mature-bdd-framework-for-net) to help you, although it's not necessary. With NUnit, you might write something like this

```
[TestFixture]
public class ExampleTests
{
    [SetUp]
    public void ExecuteScenario()
    {
        GrabBucket();
        AddApple();
        AddOrange();
        AddBanana();
    }

    [Test]
    public void ThereShouldBeOneApple()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(1, Count("Apple"));
    }

    [Test]
    public void ThereShouldBeOneOrange()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(1, "Orange");
    }

    [Test]
    public void ThereShouldBeOneBanana()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(1, "Banana");
    }

    [Test]
    public void ThereShouldBeNoPomegranates()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(0, "Pomegranate");
    }

    private void GrabBucket() { /* do stuff */ }
    private void AddApple() { /* do stuff */ }
    private void AddOrange() { /* do stuff */ }
    private void AddBanana() { /* do stuff */ }

    private int Count(string fruitType)
    {
        // Query the application state
        return 0;
    }
}
```

*I realize this doesn't answer your question as stated* - this isn't breaking the larger integration test down into smaller units - but it may help you solve the dependency problem; here, all the related tests are depending on execution of a single scenario, not of previously-executed tests.